# SQL Loop through a string, find ID, and make a view out of it

Tags: sql, sql-server

Table A [Product] Columns: ProductID, Name,and Price。

Table B [Favorite] Columns: ListID, ListName, ListContents

B.ListContents contain a list of IDs, seperated by ","  Exp: 1,2,5,6,8

Now i want to create a View that loop through each B.ListContents value, extract the number, and finds its corresponding "ProductID" "Name" "Price" from Table A。

**Result should be like:**

[image]

I know how to handle it with c# by using .Split(',')，but no clue how to handle it on SQL。

And by the way, how do you title this problem in better English? (im an ESL), Thank you.

---

Edit: I was using Azure SQL. SSMS v18.5.1

Comment: A View can't "loop". A View is simply a pseudo-table defined by a `SELECT`. Looping isn't something you want to do in an RDBMS anyway; it's not a programming language it's a Set-based language. You want to use set based solutions when using SQL, as they perform **significantly** faster than iterative solution.

Comment: *"B.ListContents contain a list of IDs, seperated by "," Exp: 1,2,5,6,8"* Ideally you should be fixing your design then. Storing delimited data is breaking one of the basic principles of Normal Form. Fix your design, fix the problem. Use a Normalised data model.

Comment: @Larnu Understood, so how should i store a list of ID more efficiently?

Comment: By using 1 row per ID, @Max .

Comment: @Larnu I see, so even it has more rows, the database runs more effeciantly i assume? thank you sir

Comment: Please always tag the question with the lowest version of SQL Server you need to support. This can have a big impact on the solutions that might be possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `string_split()`:

```
select f.listid, p.*
from favorites f cross apply
     string_split(f.listcontents) s  join
     products p
     on p.productid = s.value;
```

Then you should fix the data model!  The data model is broken, broken, broken:

- Numbers should not be stored in strings.
- Columns should have only one value (except fro JSON and XML columns).
- Foreign key relationships should be properly declares.
- SQL has poor string manipulation functions.

Comment: Thank you sir, i restructure my table

Comment: For other readers who happen upon this (and can't fix their data model), [`STRING_SPLIT()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql) requires compatibility level 130 (SQL Server 2016) or higher.

Comment: @Max . . . Good job.  What looks right in a tool such as Python or C# or Java, might not be the best way to use a SQL database.